# extract one line of content in cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have one worksheet and I need to do some filtering and extraction.

There may be multiple lines of data inside the cells under column Q.
I need to extract the LINE whenever it starts with MO.

Format of Column Q cell will be like this:

```
FM;DATE;CONTENT;NUMBER
MO;DATE;CONTENT;NUMBER
AC;DATE;CONTENT;NUMBER
```

e.g. MO;2017-06-01;Example;123.4

To be specific, I would like to extract line: MO;DATE;CONTENT;NUMBER

I do not know is it possible to do it with VBA since I am a new programmer.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this...

```
Sub example()


Dim y As Workbook
Dim Value As Variant
Dim cval As String


Set y = ThisWorkbook
lRow = y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lRow
cval = y.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)

If cval Like "*" & MO & "*" Then

POS = InStr(cval, "MO")

lpos = InStr(POS, cval, "AC")

tmp = lpos - POS

fmsg = Mid(cval, POS, tmp)

MsgBox fmsg

End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Instr helps me with the first step. How about I the beginning of the next line is uncertain. The only thing that I certain is there will be the first two letter of the next line is two Capital Letters. And I would like to extract the whole line starts with MO. I don't know is it possible to filter out any two capital letter. But anyway, thank you so much for your sincere help.

Comment: You are telling 3rd row starting letter is not only "AC", it will differ. i am right?

Comment: but "MO" should be in 2nd row?

Comment: Is number's digits are fixed ?

Comment: No they are all uncertain

Comment: There is any minimum count  of digit?

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula in any cell and it will show you the line's number:

```
=MATCH("MO;*",Q:Q, 0)
```

If you want to dusplay it in another sheet, prefix the `Q:Q` with the sheet's name:

```
 =MATCH("MO;*", 'Sheet name'!Q:Q, 0)
```